# Usage problem add_value_provider_argument on a streaming stream ( Apache beam /PYTHON)

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We want to create a custom dataflow template using the function parameters `add_value_provider_argument`

unable to launch the following command without inputting the variables defined in `add_value_provider_argument ()`

```py
class UserOptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):     
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--input_topic',
            help='The Cloud Pub/Sub topic to read from.\n'
                 '"projects/<PROJECT_NAME>/topics/<TOPIC_NAME>".'
        )
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--window_size',
            type=float,
            default=1.0,
            help='Output file\'s window size in number of minutes.'
        )
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--output_path',
            help='GCS Path of the output file including filename prefix.'
        )

def run():
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(streaming=True, save_main_session=True)
    custom_options = pipeline_options.view_as(UserOptions)

    with beam.Pipeline(options=custom_options)as pipeline:
        print ("cecei est un test", custom_options.input_topic)
        (pipeline 
         | 'Read PubSub Messages' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=custom_options.input_topic.get())
         | 'Window into' >> GroupWindowsIntoBatches(custom_options.window_size.get())
         | 'Write to GCS' >> beam.ParDo(WriteBatchesToGCS(custom_options.output_path.get()))

        )               

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

I execute this file with

```
python luckycart_check.py \
    --runner DataflowRunner \
    --project $PROJECT_NAME \
    --staging_location gs://$BUCKET_NAME/staging \
    --temp_location gs://$BUCKET_NAME/temp \
    --template_location gs://$BUCKET_NAME/templates/luckycartTEMPLATE \
```

and I get the following error:

```
 File "/home/jupyter/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/options/value_provider.py", line 106, in get
    '%s.get() not called from a runtime context' % self)
apache_beam.error.RuntimeValueProviderError: RuntimeValueProvider(option: input_topic, type: str, default_value: None).get() not called from a runtime context
(env) jupyter@luckykart:~/clement/terraform/basics$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify `--input_topic` when creating the pipeline, it will be of type `RuntimeValueProvider`, meaning you can only `get()` its value when the Dataflow job is running. This is normal.

Some transforms like `WriteToBigQuery` accept `ValueProvider` arguments (without the `.get()`). However, `ReadFromPubSub` does not currently accept `ValueProvider` arguments since it is implemented as a native transform in Dataflow.

See this documentation for more on creating templates with ValueProviders: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates

Comment: thanks  you for this feeback!!  I spent several days on this point !!!

Comment: That's great! If this answered your question please mark it as such. Thank you

Comment: Same with WriteToPubSub...it's because of the parse_topic/parse_subscription methods that expect strings and not ValueProviders. https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.5.0/_modules/apache_beam/io/gcp/pubsub.html#WriteToPubSub