# The Additional Paramates at Dataflow into Beam Pipeline

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I'm working on Dataflow, I already has build my custom pipeline via Python SDK. 
I would like to add the parameters at the Dataflow UI into my custom pipeline. 
using the Additional Parameters. Reference by https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#staticvalue

[image]

Then I changed `add_argument` to `add_value_provider_argument` follow by google docs

```
class CustomParams(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):        
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            "--input_topic",
            type = str,
        )
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            "--window_size",
            type = int,
            default = 5,
        )

def run():
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args, .....)
    custom_param = pipeline_options.view_as(CustomParams)
    .....
    pipeline | "Read PubSub Message" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(custom_param.input_topic)
```

After that, I try to making a templates to GCP. The script for upload look like

```
  python custom_pipeline.py \
    --runner DataflowRunner \
    --project YOUR_PROJECT_ID \
    --staging_location gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/staging \
    --temp_location gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/temp \
    --template_location gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE_NAME
```

But I got the error when I creating template for upload to GCS, like this

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

at the line `beam.io.ReadFromPubSub()`

It's look like the thing I got from `add_value_provider_argument` Is **RuntimeValueProvider** object.     So I'm quite confuse what I have to do for fix this?

I try to fix this problem such as

**Casting the data type**

`beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(str(custom_param.input_topic))`

But got this error,

`ValueError: PubSub topic must be in the form "projects/<project>/topics/<topic>" (got "RuntimeValueProvider(option: input_topic, type: str, default_value: '...')").`

So Please anyone have troubleshooting for this? I have no idea how to go no it.

Comment: It seems that `ReadFromPubSub` module doesn't accept `ValueProvider`. Have you checked this Stack [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58869194/9928809)?

Comment: @mk_sta So that mean It's no way to use Additional Parametes to my pipeline right? It's look like Additional Parametes send the parameter as **RuntimeValueProvider** and the ReadFromPubSub didn't support it.

Comment: I haven't checked this yet, will do further research and update here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @mk_sta

> It seems that ReadFromPubSub module doesn't accept ValueProvider. Have you checked this Stack thread?

and explained in that [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58838705/usage-problem-add-value-provider-argument-on-a-streaming-stream-apache-beam-p/58869194#58869194), `ReadFromPubSub does not currently accept ValueProvider arguments since it is implemented as a native transform in Dataflow.`

You can check [I/O methods that accept runtime parameters](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#pipeline-io-and-runtime-parameters) for the `ValueProvider` support in different SDKs.

So at this moment, if you switch from Python SDK to Java SDK, the [Read](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/pubsub/PubsubIO.java#L588) of PubSubIO does support ValueProvider.

Comment: Thx for answered but I can't change SDK haha, let more question about ** Additional Parametes** this parametes will send ```ValueProvider``` object into our pipeline right?

Comment: Yes, they will be `RuntimeValueProvider` objects.