# Passing in 'date' as a runtime argument in Google Dataflow Template

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm currently trying to generate a Google Dataflow custom template, that will call an API when run, and write the results to a BigQuery table.

However the issue I'm encountering is that the API requires a date parameter 'YYYY-MM-DD' to be passed in for it to work.

Unfortunately it seems that when constructing a template Dataflow requires that you use ValueProvider ([as described here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates)) for any variables that are relative to when the job is being run (i.e. today's date). Otherwise it'll just carry on using the same date that was generated when the template was originally created. (i.e. with dt.date.today() etc - [h/t to this post](http://amygdala.github.io/dataflow/app_engine/2017/10/22/gae_dataflow.html))

Therefore with the code that I've got, is there any way to generate the template so that it will utilise today's date correctly as an argument at runtime, rather than just using the same static date indefinitely - or as is currently the case - just not converting to a template at all.

```
from __future__ import print_function, absolute_import
import argparse
import logging
import sys

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io.gcp.internal.clients import bigquery
from apache_beam.metrics.metric import Metrics
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, GoogleCloudOptions, StandardOptions, SetupOptions
from apache_beam.options.value_provider import ValueProvider

import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta, date
import time
import re

logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

class GetAPI():
  def __init__(self, data={}, date=None):
    self.num_api_errors = Metrics.counter(self.__class__, 'num_api_errors')
    self.data = data
    self.date = date

  def get_job(self):
    import requests
    endpoint = f'https://www.rankranger.com/api/v2/?rank_stats&key={self.data.api_key}&date={self.date}'\
               f'&campaign_id={self.data.campaign}&se_id={self.data.se}&domain={self.data.domain}&output=json'
    logging.info("Endpoint: {}".format(str(endpoint)))
    try:
      res = requests.get(endpoint)
      if res.status_code == 200:
        # logging.info("Reponse: {}".format(str(res.text)))
        json_data = res.json()
        ## Store the API response
        if 'result' in json_data:
          response = json_data.get('result')
          return response

    except Exception as e:
      self.num_api_errors.inc()
      logging.error(f'Exception: {e}')
      logging.error(f'Extract error on "%s"', 'Rank API')


def format_dates(api):
  api['date'] = dt.datetime.strptime(api['date'], "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  return api


# Class to pass in date generated at runtime to template
class UserOptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        ## Special runtime argument e.g. date
        parser.add_value_provider_argument('--date',
            type=str,
            default=(dt.date.today()).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
            help='Run date in YYYY-MM-DD format.')


def run(argv=None):
    """
      Main entry point; defines the static arguments to be passed in.
    """
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--api_key',
        type=str,
        default=API_KEY,
        help='API key for Rank API.')
    parser.add_argument('--campaign',
        type=str,
        default=CAMPAIGN,
        help='Campaign ID for Rank API')
    parser.add_argument('--se',
        type=str,
        default=SE,
        help='Search Engine ID for Rank API')
    parser.add_argument('--domain',
        type=str,
        default=DOMAIN,
        help='Domain for Rank API')
    parser.add_argument('--dataset',
        type=str,
        default=DATASET,
        help='BigQuery Dataset to write tables to. Must already exist.')
    parser.add_argument('--table_name',
        type=str,
        default=TABLE_NAME,
        help='The BigQuery table name. Should not already exist.')
    parser.add_argument('--project',
        type=str,
        default=PROJECT,
        help='Your GCS project.')
    parser.add_argument('--runner',
        type=str,
        default="DataflowRunner",
        help='Type of DataFlow runner.')

    args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

    # Create and set your PipelineOptions.
    options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    user_options = options.view_as(UserOptions)

    pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options=options)

    # Gets data from Rank Ranger API
    api = (
        pipeline
        | 'create' >> beam.Create(GetAPI(data=args, date=user_options.date).get_job())
        | 'format dates' >> beam.Map(format_dates)
    )

    # Write to bigquery based on specified schema
    BQ = (api | "WriteToBigQuery" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(args.table_name, args.dataset, SCHEMA))

    pipeline.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

As you can see from the error message, rather than passing in a neatly formatted 'YYYY-MM-DD' parameter, it's instead passing in the full ValueProvider object which is stopping the API call from working and returning the NoneType error.

```
(Apache) C:\Users\user.name\Documents\Alchemy\Dataflow\production_pipeline\templates>python main.py --runner DataflowRunner --project <PROJECT> --staging_location gs://<STORAGE-BUCKET>/staging --temp_location gs://<STORAGE-BUCKET>/temp --template_location gs://<STORAGE-BUCKET>/template/<TEMPLATE> --region europe-west2
INFO:root:Endpoint: https://www.rankranger.com/api/v2/?rank_stats&key=<API_KEY>&date=RuntimeValueProvider(option: date, type: str, default_value: '2020-08-25')&campaign_id=<CAMPAIGN>&se_id=<SE>&domain=<DOMAIN>&output=json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 267, in <module>
    run()
  File "main.py", line 257, in run
    | 'format dates' >> beam.Map(format_dates)
  File "C:\Users\user.name\Anaconda3\envs\Apache\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\transforms\core.py", line 2590, in __init__
    self.values = tuple(values)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: I assume here that `beam.Create()` transform doesn't accept `ValueProvider` passed arguments. For any runtime parameter defined in `add_value_provider_argument` you just have returned `RuntimeValueProvider` object. Have you read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62311054/9928809) explaining the similar behavior?

Comment: How are you running the job? For gcloud, for example, you can set `TODAY=\`date +%Y-%m-%d\`` and add `--parameters date=$TODAY`

Comment: Hi @PeterKim, Thank you for this info, I will check out whether I can incorporate these when running the build template command :) I'm attempting to run it through Google Dataflow - with the aim being to turn the pipeline.py script into a template (which is saved to Cloud Storage), and then have Google Dataflow run that template on a scheduled basis (using Cloud Scheduler + Pub/Sub).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in your diagnosis. You should consider migrating to [Flex Templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates) which solve this (and other) issues and provide much more flexibility.